# How can I order a jQuery wrapped set?

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to get the top-most ".ui-dialog" element in a wrapped set.

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
var topDialog = $(".ui-dialog").orderBy("[style*=z-index]").eq(0);
```

Is there a nicer way to do this than writing a loop to check the values?

**Edit:** Just to clarify... I need to be able to get the top-most element at any given point during the life of the page (after multiple dialogs are opened and closed). Nick Craver's answer to use the maxZ variable doesn't seem to work since the variable is not decremented when dialogs are removed.

Here's the loop I'm using now when I close a dialog that seems kind of ugly to me:

```
// Enable printing of the top-most dialog or #page
if ($(".ui-dialog").length > 0) {

    var top = $(".ui-dialog").first();

    $(".ui-dialog").each(function () {
        if ($(this).css("z-index") > top.css("z-index")) {
            top = $(this);
        }
    });

    top.removeClass("dont-print");

} else {

    $("#page").removeClass("dont-print");

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the dialogs are made to stack, the variable of the top `z-index` is actually maintained and accessible, it's: `$.ui.dialog.maxZ`, [you can see how it's set here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.6/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L257-263).

So instead of ordering, you can just see which dialog has that highest index (only one will), like this:

```
var topDialog = $(".ui-dialog").filter(function() { 
                  return $(this).css("z-index") == $.ui.dialog.maxZ;
                });
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/n6UKB/).

Comment: I un-selected your answer because after tying it out, it appears that the maxZ variable is never decremented when dialogs are removed (either with .remove() or .dialog("destroy")). I should have been more clear in stating that I need the top-most dialog every time a new dialog is added or removed so that I can set some CSS classes that allow only the top-most dialog to print.

Comment: @Terminal - in that case you should use a loop, like you have (though I'd cache `top.css("z-index")`, no need to run it every time), you can see in my answer that's exactly how jQuery UI determined `maxZ`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always make a custom selector too :)

```
jQuery.expr[':'].highestModal = function(node) {
    return $(node).css('z-index') == $.ui.dialog.maxZ;
};
```

Borrowing from [Nick Craver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299901/how-can-i-order-a-jquery-wrapped-set/4300190#4300190) (I hope he doesn't mind :P Have an upvote! )

Use it like so...

```
$('.ui-dialog:highestModal');
```

Comment: I mean....sure? You plan on using this code more than once? :)  Selectors are more expensive, you'd have to be using it a lot to justify this IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function clearUiMaxZ() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ui.dialog.overlay.maxZ = 0;
            $.ui.dialog.maxZ = 0;
        }, 100);
    }
```

Call this function on Dialog Close , this will reset the maxZ.